# using generic attribute in C#

Tags: c#, generics, attributes, xunit, c#-11.0

I want to use generic attribute for tests, and create a method which must invoke before test.
So, I create

```
public class EnsureItemExistAttribute<T> : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
        where T : class
    {
        T item;

        public EnsureItemExistAttribute(T item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }
         ...
    }
```

and this compile ok
But when I use it `[EnsureItemExist<Subtitle>(item: new Subtitle())]`, this cause

> Compiler Error CS0181 Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0181  Attribute constructor parameter 'item' has type 'Subtitle', which is not a valid attribute parameter type   Streetcode.XIntegrationTest D:\StreedCode\StreedCode\StreetCode\Streetcode\Streetcode.XIntegrationTest\ControllerTests\AdditionalContent\SubtitleControllerTests.cs 75  Active

Can you explain me, what is wrong with this and how to fix it? Thanks:)

Comment: Attributes can only have primitive types as constructor parameters (e.g. string, int, bool etc.)

Comment: So, this means there is no way to pass instance of some class here ?

Comment: Correct, you can new up the class inside the attribute, but you can't do it inside the `[...]`

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Attributes allow only very limited subset of types to be used as parameters (`string`, `object`, `Type`, single dimensional arrays, some primitive types like `int`, `bool`, etc.) and limited subset of expressions (literal constants, `new` for arrays, `typeof`) to be used to provide values.

##### Detailed

Generic attributes were introduced in C# 11 to ease providing type info for attributes, i.e. to replace parameters like `Type = typeof(...)`. From the [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/generic-attributes):

> Currently attribute authors can take a System.Type as a parameter and have users pass a typeof expression to provide the attribute with types that it needs. However, outside of analyzers, there's no way for an attribute author to constrain what types are allowed to be passed to an attribute via typeof. If attributes could be generic, then attribute authors could use the existing system of type parameter constraints to express the requirements for the types they take as input.

The rest of restrictions applied to attribute parameters are still the same. From the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#213-attribute-specification):

> An expression `E` is an *attribute_argument_expression* if all of the following statements are true:

> - The type of `E` is an attribute parameter type.
> - At compile-time, the value of `E` can be resolved to one of the following:
>
>   - A constant value.
>   - A `System.Type` object obtained using a *typeof_expression* specifying a non-generic type, a closed constructed type, or an unbound generic type , but not an open type.
>   - A single-dimensional array of *attribute_argument_expression*s.

[And](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#2124-attribute-parameter-types):

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the ***attribute parameter types***, which are:

> - One of the following types: `bool`, `byte`, `char`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `sbyte`, `short`, `string`, `uint`, `ulong`, `ushort`.
> - The type `object`.
> - The type `System.Type`.
> - Enum types.
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.
> - A constructor argument or public field that does not have one of these types, shall not be used as a positional or named parameter in an attribute specification.

So you can provide values for `T` which are compile time constants (for example if `T` is `string`, `int`, ... and you provide value via literal), `Type` obtained via `typeof` or an array of previous, and limited to aformentioned subset of types.

I.e. for example the following will work:

```cs
[EnsureItemExistAttribute<string[]>(new []{"1", "abc"})]
[EnsureItemExistAttribute<string>("sdas")]
[EnsureItemExistAttribute<object>(null)]
```

But you can't provide an instance of arbitrary type.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with generic attributes, you get the same error with a concrete type.

Comment: @DavidG yes, which is explicitly written in the answer _"The rest of restrictions applied to attribute parameters are still the same"_

Comment: So why spend the first half of your answer talking about generic attributes?

Comment: @DavidG I think to give the context of what generic attributes are and why this feature was introduced can help to understand can be useful for OP., because I think part of the attempt in the question comes from this misunderstanding.

Comment: The answer looks fine to me, but I would consider moving the conclusion, i.e. it works for literal values, to the top, before the quotes of the language specification.